# Sublime Text 3 dpkg error

Tags: command-line, 16.04, sublime-text

I want to install Sublime Text 3 , but had a problem, my terminal is showing this error:

> dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process

What shall I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because `apt-get` is being used already. Close the Ubuntu software center, and if you are using `dpkg` or `apt-get` on a different tab, wait for it to finish.

If that doesn't work try rebooting.

If you don't want to reboot, try:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Note that this could break your system and it should only be used if everything else doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `sudo` to your commands and check if `apt-get` is already busy. If `apt-get` is busy wait for it to finish.

### METHOD 1 USING PPA

Here are the steps to install Sublime text 3 using PPA:

Add Sublime text 3 PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
```

Install sublime text

```
 sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Create symbolic link so that you can run ST3 from terminal by typing subl

```
sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text /usr/bin/subl
```

Just to make sure if it's installed properly , try running it from terminal by typing

```
 subl
```

### METHOD 2 USING DEB PACKAGE

Install ST3 from deb file :

Download deb package:

Head over to [Sublime text website](https://www.sublimetext.com/) and download the deb package by clicking on *Download for Ubuntu* .

Change directory to location where you have saved the downloaded file:

If you have downloaded the deb in Download directory then in terminal type

```
cd Downloads/
```

this will change your directory to Downloads.

Install the package:

At present it's named sublime-text_build-3103_amd64.deb , for future release, replace the package name with new package name)

```
dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3103_amd64.deb
```

> Note: If there are some errors with unresolved dependencies, run
>   `apt-get install -f` afterwards.
>
> In case you face any issues or have doubt read [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) and [Install from a deb
>   file, by dpkg -i or by apt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/install-from-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt)

Comment: You don't need a PPA for Sublime Text 3, in fact I would actively discourage it. `.deb` files for Ubuntu are available for [download](https://sublimetext.com/3), and it will remind you to upgrade when a new version is released. The debs also create `/usr/bin/subl` and other files, so the PPA is pointless at this point.

Comment: @MattDMo Sir as I'm new to Linux and as far as my understanding goes on PPA,  I think I'd use PPAs before I use .debs because with a PPA you may at least have the possibility of getting security updates once in a while,whereas with a .deb you've just got to fend for yourself and try to stay on top of them. If there is anything else that I should be aware off then please let me know.

Comment: What I was saying is that as far as Sublime goes, the program itself will let you know when an update is available, so a Sublime PPA is pretty much pointless, as it will lag behind the original version until the maintainers decide to update. PPAs in general are not bad at all, I didn't want to give that impression, it's just in this particular situation I don't think it is warranted.

Comment: Ohh! Thank you. I will update the answer soon.